# Getting total cpu time spent on debian process (even for short-live processes)

Tags: linux, bash, cpu, shell, debian-stretch

for my master's thesis I'm trying to get resource usage information about MQTT brokers on a debian machine.

I'm having troubles finding a way to find out how much total cpu time debian has spent on a process I'm doing resource usage statistics for. I've tried out pidstat and cpustat to get cpu statistics about this process, but either:

- the cpu time is shown as a percentage (pidstat)
- minimal measuring interval of 1s is too small for short-lived processes(cpustat).

Can anyone try to lead me to a way I can find out how much total CPU time (or even CPU cycles) a process has used?

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser! What Debian version is this? Buster (10), Stretch (9), or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is debian-stretch!

Answer (score 3):

**[atop](https://linux.die.net/man/1/atop)** is a great tool that should work for your case. It is an improved `top` tool with accounting (which is exactly what you need for the reasons I'll write out next).

**`atop`** is a daemon that accounts for a lot of statistics per X seconds (however you configure it, default on Debian is 60s) and it saves a history of all processes and their usages on the system, basically like **`top`** snapshots.

**`atop`** also has the functionality to print out specific statistics in a parseable format:

```
atop -r /var/log/atop/atop_<date> -P <format>
```

This will read the process history from a log file from the specified date and print it out in a machine parseable format specific for certain statistics.

The format you need is **PRC**:

```
PRC  Process and thread level totals.
            This  line  contains the total cpu time consumed in system mode (`sys') and in user mode (`user'), the total number of processes present at this moment (`#proc'), the total number of threads present at this moment in state `running' (`#trun'), `sleeping
            interruptible' (`#tslpi') and `sleeping uninterruptible' (`#tslpu'), the number of zombie processes (`#zombie'), the number of clone system calls (`clones'), and the number of processes that ended during the interval (`#exit') when process accounting is
            used. Instead of `#exit` the last column may indicate that process accounting could not be activated (`no procacct`).
            If the screen-width does not allow all of these counters, only a relevant subset is shown.
```

For example, with the following command you will get an output like the following:

```
$ atop -r /var/log/atop/atop_20200617 -P PRC
PRC hostname 1592403710 2020/06/17 14:21:50 5000098 377 (google_osconfig) S 100 262341 41122 0 120 0 0 0 0 377 y
```

Where the total SYS CPU time is `262341` and total USR CPU time is `41122` for the process `google_osconfig` with PID `377`.

**`atopacct.service`** is the service that does the accounting and it is a deamon, so it accounts even for short-running processes.

---

You can install it on Debian 9 via the package manager:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atop
```

And it will automatically start accounting.
You can read more in the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/atop).

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I was able to use atop 1 > logfile.txt.
I forgot to mention that I have to do the resource usage via ssh, that's why using the atop -r command does not work well, since it is an interactive mode. I'd have to download the logfile and then do the reading on my local linux distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `time(1)`. It may not be accurate enough for really short-lived processes though.

Keep in mind [the `time` shell builtin is not the `time` standalone executable](https://superuser.com/a/1505454/432690). In Bash `help time` describes the builtin; `man 1 time` describes the executable.

If you can run the tool you want to measure by yourself (i.e. you choose the command to run) then it's quite simple. Instead of `the-tool argument1 argument2` run

```
time the-tool argument1 argument2
# or
/usr/bin/time the-tool argument1 argument2
```

If `the-tool` is run by some other tool and you cannot easily make it run `time the-tool …` instead, then create a wrapper script:

1. Move `the-tool` to another name, e.g. `the-real-tool`.
2. Create a script named `the-tool`, make it executable and reachable via `$PATH`. The content:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec /usr/bin/time the-real-tool "$@"
   ```

(Alternatively you may not rename `the-tool`, but only place the script as `the-tool` in a directory that appears early in `$PATH`, so the other tool will find the script when it tries to run `the-tool`. Inside the script you need a *full* path to the real `the-tool`, so the script doesn't run itself recursively.)

Study `man 1 time` and notice `--format` and `--output` options. You may want to use `-a --output` especially in the wrapper script to collect results automatically:

```
#!/bin/sh
log="/tmp/the-tool-$(date --rfc-3339=seconds)-$$.log"
printf '<%s> ' "$0" "$@" >"$log"
printf '\n' >>"$log"
exec /usr/bin/time -a --output="$log" the-real-tool "$@"
```

If you use `bash` and its builtin then you can measure [with greater precision](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70655/108618). Logging output only from `time` is [somewhat tricky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126057/108618) in this case, yet possible:

```
#!/bin/bash
log="/tmp/the-tool-$(date --rfc-3339=seconds)-$$.log"
printf '<%s> ' "$0" "$@" >"$log"
printf '\n' >>"$log"
{ time the-real-tool "$@" 2>&3; } 3>&2 2>>"$log"
```

---

The overhead of `time` is researched in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1517563/432690). It should be negligible in comparison to the resolution of `time`, especially for the builtin. In case of a wrapper script the interpreter (`sh` or `bash`) will add to the total time as well, but not to the results reported by `time`. In other words the results from measuring `the-real-tool` should not be inflated but you'll need to wait little longer for `the-tool`-script than you would wait for `the-tool`-original (a.k.a. `the-real-tool` now).